# How to trigger :redrawstatus to a different window?

Tags: statusline

Is there a way to invoke :redrawstatus from a window that is different than the window whose statusline is to be updated ?  Not a global :redrawstatus to all windows, but to one specific window.

Comment: not without changing the window